How to minimize cost of drawing 1-2 objects while keeping them bright enough to see?
I have a really simple scene that includes only one or two 3D objects, and the rest of it is UI. My target is WebGL so I am taking every chance to optimize thing as much as possible.
The game objects are shown on the UI with a render texture and I have a directional light to make it not dark. I use realtime light because the objects have a simple rotation animation.
My question is: can I maybe bake light on it to make it light from all sides even if it is animating (I don't want any special light effect just make it not dark is enough) and, because it is only one gameobject (or maybe 2 because it has 2 parts), does baking makes any sense?

Any question of the form "how is performance affected by _____" can be answered by profiling. Try it both ways, and measure the time taken per frame in each case. That cuts through any uncertainty, and gives you the correct answer for your specific use case in your context on your target hardware - way better than hearsay from the Internet. But, if you just want it lighter, have you considered using a shader that's unlit or has a "fake" lighting built in, so you don't need any lights whatsoever - not baked, not realtime?

Hm didn't occur to me, but shader can be the best solution tnx.

Ended up using Unlit material instead of light.
